# Undefined method `lambda' in ruby code

Tags: ruby

I have a code

```
class A < BasicObject

    def initialize var1, *args, &block
      if var1 == :lambda
        @var1 = lambda &block
      end
    end
end

a = A.new :lambda, 123  do |var|
  puts "ha ha ha"
end
```

why does it cause an error?

```
undefined method `lambda' for #<A:0x00000001687968> (NoMethodError)
```

unlike this one (it doesn't cause it)

```
class A
   def initialize var1, *args, &block
      if var1 == :lambda
        @var1 = lambda &block
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `lambda` method is defined in the `Kernel` module. `Object` includes `Kernel`. `BasicObject` does not. So if you want to use `lambda` from a BasicObject, you have to call it as `::Kernel.lambda`.

Note that this is not specific to `lambda` - it applies to any other Kernel method (like e.g. `puts`) as well.

PS: Note that `@var1 = lambda &block` does the same thing as just writing `@var1 = block`, so the use of `lambda` isn't actually necessary here.

Comment: what should I do to use lambda then?

Comment: @AlanDert I've expanded my answer.

Comment: @AlanDert Ah, sorry, my bad. `::Kernel` then.

Comment: `Note that @var1 = lambda &block does the same thing as just writing @var1 = block` Can you please give a link where it's explained? I already ready about blocks, lambdas, proc and there was no information about it.

Comment: @AlanDert Where what's explained? Or asked differently: What do you expect `@var1 = lambda &block` to do differently than `@var1 = block`?

Comment: @AlanDert I'm sorry, but I did not ask a yes or no question.

Comment: `Note that @var1 = lambda &block does the same thing as just writing @var1 = block` Why is that the same?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22609/discussion-between-sepp2k-and-alan-dert)

Answer (score 0):

You are using BasicObject as base class which is an explicit Blank class and specifically does not include Kernel, so you need the qualifier ::Kernel when you access any Kernel method.

On a separate note -

Instead of passing an argument that you have a block you can use the Kernel method block_given? 
So taking your example -

```
class A
  def initialize  *args, &block
    if block_given?
      @var1 = lambda &block
    end
    puts @var1.call
  end
end
a = A.new  123  do |var|
  puts "ha ha ha"
end
```